# How to completely disable light-locker and replace it with GDM lockscreen

Tags: cinnamon

I am using cinnamon and I really like it but the only problem I have is I do not want `light-locker` every time I do `ctrl + alt + l` I want the gdm lockscreen to show when I press those keys. I tried to disable the lightlocker systemctl but it doesn't have one. How do I get rid of it? I did install gdm just want to make it replace lightdm completely.

Answer (score 0):

I do not use Cinnamon, but this should work to disable lightdm and enable gdm:

1) During bootup, press ctl-alt-F2, which will put you into a command-line interface before the X windows interface is activated.

2) Login as appropriate.

3) sudo systemctl lightdm stop

3.5) sudo systemctl lightdm status  (should now be inactive)

4) sudo systemctl gdm start

4.5) sudo systemctl gdm status (should now be active)

5) sudo reboot

Comment: I don't think it is lightdm because after removing it I still have this annoying screensaver. I think it is the screensaver in Cinnamon which I can't find systemctl